# Special sign in code - use it or not?

Tags: c#, special-characters, sign

I observed in one c# app code like this:

```
string message = String.Format("{0}", "▼");
```

Is this code proper? Won't the sign "▼" cause any errors in the future?

Comment: What makes you think this is a problem?

Comment: As long as the character is valid Unicdoe it should be fine both now and in the future.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a special character in code, it's a string value stored in a variable. No one cares as long as it's a valid Unicode (and this char is).

However, part `String.Format("{0}", "▼");` doesn't make much sense.
Simple `string message = "▼";` would do just fine.

You could even use `char mySpecialChar = '▼';`, which would make even more sense, because you don't need a string variable for a single character.

Answer (score 1):

From the C# specification:

> A source file is an ordered sequence of Unicode characters.

and

> For maximal portability, it is recommended that files in a file system be encoded with the UTF-8 encoding.

UTF-8 is one a several encodings (mappings from character codes to byte sequences) for the Unicode character set.

I'm not sure why you are referring to ▼ as a *special* character anyway. It's use in C# source code is identical to the use of $. It *is* in the [Symbol Other [So]](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/So/list.htm) Unicode category.

So, as far as tools that support the programming environment you are using, it's fine and proper.

But—I bring this up because others claim to have this misfortune—if you use tools that don't support Unicode/UTF-8 then you might find a lower common denominator by writing characters outside the range of U+0000 to U+007F as C# Unicode escape sequences (\uHHHH) and still saving as UTF-8 since an ASCII processor will interpret them identically. It is possible to rewrite every C# source file character in this format (whether in a literal `string` or `char` or in an identifier). *But, if your tools don't support UTF-8 for C# source files then you'll probably have problems with other text files in your project!*

---

As for can and how a UI will display a particular character, it depends on the renderer and fonts available on the system. If the Unicode string is being rendered in a different character set then the renderer has options (throw an exception, drop, substitute a similar character or substitute a replacement character). WinForms render in Unicode, web pages typically do, and console programs usually not. To check or change a console's encoding (code page) use `chcp` (Linux: `locale`).

Once the characters are output, the UI has to have a font that supports them. If it doesn't then a replacement glyph is often displayed (the same glyph as for this character ▯).  In WinForms, you can pick a font for each control so it's up to you. For web pages, you can suggest fonts for each text element and even provide fonts as HTTP resources. Consoles are set for one font by the user; So, that scenario might be the most problematic.  To check or change a Windows console's font, right-click on the title bar and select Properties.

My console (Windows's cmd.exe) defaults to code page 437 and Lucinda Console which do handle and display ▼.

Answer (score 0):

So, regardless of encoding, this sign will be always the same when app shows it on the UI?